# How to merge the content of files tracked by Git LFS

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have an XML model (100 MB) in Git, that changes frequently and grows in size. I was considering using Git LFS to handle it.

By checking the documentation I am not sure if Git LFS supports the actual merge of the files, or when conflicts arise a "ours" or "theirs" approach should be followed.

Does Git LFS support the actual merge of the "real" content of the tracked files?

---- UPDATE 1----

I installed Git LFS on my computer, to track .xml files. Hence, the content of my XML model is no longer XML content, but a pointer to the Git LFS server. Here is how my XML file looks like now.

```
 version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
 oid sha256:0e23dcebda1977c424e5d0f25fda57d6eff9c2a5bbb6df7dd4985b64cf437d20
 size 53
```

Hence, if I change this XML file in two branches and try to merge, it raises a conflict. And when I open the XML file to resolve the conflict, I need to choose between one oid and the other:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
oid sha256:0e23dcebda1977c424e5d0f25fda57d6eff9c2a5bbb6df7dd4985b64cf437d20
size 53
=======
oid sha256:cbe18ff9b73fad7d5b9cdcd177f9be9cf25bc88db279f3136aed5bfdec7eb0f7
size 91554569
>>>>>>> refs/heads/LFSbr1
```

---- UPDATE 2---

This is what I get when executing "git lfs env":

```
WARNING: Reading LFS config from ".gitconfig", not ".lfsconfig". Rename to    ".lfsconfig" before Git LFS v2.0 to remove this warning.
git-lfs/1.3.1 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.6.3; git 9c9dffb)
git version 2.9.0

LocalWorkingDir=
LocalGitDir=
LocalGitStorageDir=
LocalMediaDir=lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDir=
TempDir=lfs/tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=3
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
BatchTransfer=true
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic
UploadTransfers=basic
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```

Anything wrong in it?

Comment: I meet the same problem，any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does. There's no difference related with the merge operation, between the LFS content and the non-LFS one. Git will manage the merge, not Git LFS.

I think the following line is missing in your "git lfs env":

```
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
```

Be sure that your $HOME/.gitconfig has the following lines:

```
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
```

Comment: Yes, but since the content of this XML file is now a (git-lfs)pointer what i get merged is not the model, but the pointers. I don´t know if im explaining myself... Check the update

Comment: Have you installed the git-lfs in your local machine? If you have installed it, you must see the real XML file (not the pointer one). I run a test in my machine and "git merge" worked as expected resolving the conflict pretty good.

Comment: Yes I did install it....  Any other guesses why I am not able to actually merge the content of my model?

Comment: Check you env executing "git lfs env"

Comment: Uhm... interesting... I updated the answer with some env info.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, Git LFS is meant for binary content (images, PDF) or large, generated, files (zip, compiled files).
If the XML files are generated by some process, running it should rebuild the file with the most recent data. Otherwise, if those files are made and modified by multiple user, I think you have to track them as code to be able to solve merge conflicts.